# What has to be done in order to activate the partition plugin for MySQL 8 under Debian?

Tags: mysql, debian, database-partitioning

I have this relatively new MySQL 8 install on Debian 10, and I'm anticipating some tables to grow quite large (a new feature is only 3 months old and there are already a few thousands row in a few tables), so I was looking ahead for possibly partition these tables. However the plugin seems to be missing in my installation.

1. How can I verify that it's actually there?
2. How can I install/activate it?

I have tried `SHOW PLUGINS` but it's not listed.

Comment: use this little example https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/mysql-partition.php and see if it works, afaik you don't need a plugin for that

Answer (score 2):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning.html says:

> As of MySQL 5.7.17, the generic partitioning handler in the MySQL server is deprecated, and is removed in MySQL 8.0, when the storage engine used for a given table is expected to provide its own (“native”) partitioning handler. Currently, only the InnoDB and NDB storage engines do this.

So it's normal in MySQL 8.0 that the partition plugin is not present. It's no longer a feature of MySQL to have storage-engine independent partitioning.

PS: A few thousand rows in three months is not rapid data growth by most standards. Probably not enough to require use of partitioning anyway.

Comment: So, if I read you right, you're saying that InnoDB will partition on it's own when needed, right? As for data growth, it will be expoentially growing. It's hard to explain how this data comes from or how it grows in a short SO question, and without revealing too much of our processes.

Comment: No, you still have to use the `PARTITION BY ...` syntax shown in the documentation. If you don't, an InnoDB table will be stored as a single tablespace by default. The difference in 8.0 is not a difference in usage, it's only a difference in internal implementation.